# I can't cURL my docker composed stack from inside a Github Action

Tags: docker, curl, docker-compose, github-actions

I'm currently spinning up a docker composed stack from within a GitHub action exactly as I would locally.

I'm then just running a quick test to see if the stack is up and running at where it should be, e.g., `https://0.0.0.0:8001` with the following command:

```
- name: Test that the Perseus API stack is up and running with curl
  run: |
    sleep 30
    curl -s --retry 10 --retry-connrefused --insecure https://0.0.0.0:8001
```

However, I am just seeing the following failed output:

```
Error: Process completed with exit code 35.
```

which points to a "SSL connect error. The SSL handshaking failed." error code from the curl manual, but I am specifically setting the curl to be --insecure and bypass SSL (I think).

Would anyone know why this would be working locally, but failing inside a Github action context?

N.B. Locally, when I run that command with the stack running like it would be in the action, I get the expected response.

Please let me know if you need to see my full workflow .yaml file for this, or anything else that would be relevant ...

Comment: Use `curl -v` to get more info.

Comment: Have you resolved this? I'm having the same issue but my curl exit code is 7 failed to connect to host